# Developing an Image Processing DSL in Scala - Suggest Libraries

Tags: java, scala, image-processing, dsl

We are developing an internal DSL in Scala for Image Processing domain. The DSL is supposed to offer the functionalities similar to MATLAB. We intend to develop this DSL as a wrapper over existing Java Image Processing libraries. However since we have no prior experience with image processing in Java, we are finding it hard to decide upon a Java library to use for our project. So far we have come across Java Advanced Imaging Utilities (which was too low level for our taste) and JMagick (which doesn't have any online tutorial available it seems). What Image Processing libraries would you recommend us to use, considering ease of development and given a very short deadline? (The efficiency of the resulting library does not concern us much.)

PS: This is a bachelor level project.

Comment: This is narrow enough, but the community might migrate this to programmers.stackexchange.com. Have a look at that site, if you think it is a better fit for your question, just flag your question and let us know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out [ScalaLab](http://code.google.com/p/scalalab/), which does not yet to my knowledge incorporate an image processing library, but fits the "DSL + Matlab functionality" meme.

The largest open-source image-processing software package that I know of is [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/), with the bundle [Fiji](http://pacific.mpi-cbg.de/wiki/index.php/Fiji) incorporating a particularly large number of routines.  This certainly has the high level and power that you might want (at the module level, anyway), but it might be too high level for your purposes.

Comment: I also recommend ImageJ; it's API is compact and very easy to use. In particular, you will want to look at the ij.process package which contains the classes used for the actual image processing. (The core class to focus on is ImageProcessor.) The other packages are mainly related to ImageJ's UI code. If needed it's in a Maven repo located here -> http://code.google.com/p/mbari-maven-repository/